# How do I display values from other tables in a database in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am displaying all the items in my database table

There is a category table in my database as well
that has these values

Table item has attributes(ItemID, Name, Price, categoryID(FK))
Table category has attributes(categoryID(PK), Name, Description)

```
CategoryID    Name        
1             Pizza
2             Burgers
```

Now when I display the items it gets displayed in this order

```
Item Name      Category Price(USD)
Cheese Burger  2        7
Chicken Pizza  1        10
```

instead of the category ID I want the Category name to be displayed like this

```
Item Name      Category Price(USD)
Cheese Burger  Burger   7
Chicken Pizza  Pizza    10
```

Here is my SQL query that I have written

```
if(isset($_POST['search1'])){
    $searchKey1 = $_POST['search1'];
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE Name LIKE '%$searchKey1%'";

}
else{
    $sql1 = "SELECT item.*,category.Name FROM item, category where item.CategoryID=category.CategoryID";
    $searchKey1 ="";
}
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
```

html part

```
<p><strong>Displaying Menu by Item</strong></p>
<p><a href="add_items.php">Add Items</a></p>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
  </tr>
  <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result1)) {?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row->Name?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->CategoryID?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->Price?></td>
    <td><a href="delete_item.php?id=<?php echo $row->ItemID ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete</a></td>
    <td><a href="edit_items.php?id=<?php echo $row->ItemID ?>"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>Edit</a></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an alias in the second query:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT item.*,category.Name as categoryName FROM item, category where item.CategoryID=category.CategoryID";
```

And modify the Category column values:

```
<td><?php echo $row->categoryName?></td>
```